# How to stop SwiftUI view from getting wider than superview

Tags: layout, swiftui

I created a `UIHostingController` to put a SwiftUI view in my app. The root view contains a `VStack`, and inside that some `HStack`s and `Picker`s. The picker pushes the view wider than the screen by 8 points. It looks bad - text is slightly off screen. Usually I would fix this with auto layout constraints that pin the left and right edges of the view to the superview, with priority 1000 (required). What is the equivalent in SwiftUI?

Some boiled down code that triggers the problem

```
struct EditSegmentView: View {

    @State var seconds: Int = 10

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Pause after intro")
                Spacer()
                Text("10 seconds")
            }
            Picker(selection: $seconds, label: Text("Seconds")) {
                ForEach(0..<60) { n in
                    Text("\(n) sec").tag(n)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That is displayed from a `UIViewController`, like this:

```
let editView = EditSegmentView()
let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: editView)
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
present(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: Can you include your code please?

Comment: Yes, I just updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything obviously wrong with the code provided. You could try using a `GeometryReader` to force the `VStack` to be the width of the available space. Also add some `padding(`), because otherwise your `Text` will start right at the edge

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        VStack {
            //...
        }   .padding()
            .frame(width: proxy.size.width)
    }
}
```

Are there any clues as to why the view is expanding beyond the edges when you debug its view hierarchy?

Comment: I just tried the `GeometryReader` and the `.frame` modifier on the `VStack`. I can see in the view hierarchy debugger that the `VStack` has "modifier" width = 320 (in the object inspector in right hand side bar), and yet the size inspector shows width 328. Same thing if I try `maxWidth`.

Comment: It is really strange. Will setting a bigger padding work around this? Maybe .padding(20)? It's not rally a solution since it's difficult to understand what the actual problem is in this case, but maybe it will help

Answer (score 1):

This is a little late, but I had the same issue and fixed by making sure the outer VStack had it's alignment set to .leading. The inner Vstack also has alignment: leading and then added a .padding() to the inner VStack